# Python mechanize not recognizing form

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm trying to login at [this page](https://order.papajohns.com/secure/signin/frame.html?destination=http%3a%2f%2forder.papajohns.com%2findex.html%3fsite%3dWEB%26dclid%3d%2525n-2543611-4121096-71899047-246709315-0%26esvt%3d336192-GOUSe339376223%26esvq%3dpapa%2520johns%26esvadt%3d999999-0-3934985-1%26esvcrea%3d41751468573%26esvplace%26esvd%3dc%26esvaid%3d30536%26gclid%3dCI2psOHqtbwCFRPxOgodr0gAAg).

```
br = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

current_page = br.open(LOGIN_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(current_page.get_data())
current_page.set_data(soup.prettify())
br.set_response(current_page)

 print soup.findAll('form')

 assert br.viewing_html()

 for f in br.forms():
     print f.name
```

But it prints None for the forms even though BeautifulSoup is finding the form perfectly. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    import mechanize
    import cookielib

    br = mechanize.Browser()

    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()

    br.set_cookiejar(cj)

    host = 'https://order.papajohns.com/secure/signin/frame.html?destination=http%3a%2f%2forder.papajohns.com%2findex.html%3fsite%3dWEB%26dclid%3d%2525n-2543611-4121096-71899047-246709315-0%26esvt%3d336192-GOUSe339376223%26esvq%3dpapa%2520johns%26esvadt%3d999999-0-3934985-1%26esvcrea%3d41751468573%26esvplace%26esvd%3dc%26esvaid%3d30536%26gclid%3dCI2psOHqtbwCFRPxOgodr0gAAg'

    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
    br.open(host)
    br.form = list(br.forms())[0]
    br.form['userName'] = username
    br.form['pwd'] = password
    submit = br.submit()
    code = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(code)
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Any idea why the form was being listed before?

Comment: My guess is it probably didn't have a name, so mechanize recognized it by the first form in `list(br.forms()[0]` with 0 being the first form on the page.